# ElasticSearch use aggregated external value in scripted_metric params

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use value of aggregated sum present in `incident_sum` to be used in params of `scripted_metric`. So how do I use that, currently it gives as string "incident_sum". Please help. Given below query and its result:
    query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "incident_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "Incident ID" } },
    "group_by_sl_met": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "params": {
                    "field":"incident_sum"

        },
        "map_script": "",
        "init_script": "state['map'] =['fixed': 0, 'notfixed': 0, 'result': params.field]",
        "reduce_script": "return states;",
        "combine_script": "return state;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have already scanned a lot of stuff but unable to get any result out of it please help with this scenario.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  If you can clarify what exact outcome you are expecting, what you are trying, and what result you are getting instead, it will help your question be more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: so currently I am not able to use value of incident_sum inside params.field in scripted_metric. So suppose if value of incident_sum is 45 then it is not reflected inside params field.So current result is:{"aggregations": {
  "incident_sum": {
   "value": 45
  },
  "group_by_sl_met": {
   "value": [{
     "map": {
      "result": "incident_sum",
      "notfixed": 0,
      "fixed": 2
     }
    },
    {
     "map": {
      "result": "incident_sum",
      "notfixed": 0,
      "fixed": 0
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}